# How to convert Y-m-d date to UTC datetime?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to select rows which date is bigger than 2018-05-12. But when i convert it using Carbon `toDateTimeString()` function it adds current time. How to convert to UTC datetime like `moment.toISOString()` function?

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2018-05-12")->toDateTimeString();
```

results

> 2018-05-12 20:26:56

```
moment("2018-05-12").toISOString()
```

results

> 2018-05-11T21:00:00.000Z

Comment: Maybe carbon's setToStringFormat function?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Carbon::parse('2018-05-12', $fromTimezone)->setTimezone('UTC')->toDateTimeString();
```

You don't need to pass `$fromTimezone` if you have it defined in your `config/app.php` file.